# Discarding letters except numbers with cin

Tags: c++, input

I have this loop right now that reads in numbers and outputs them in decimal, octal, and hexadecimal:

```
while(1) {
    if (cin >> n)
    cout << internal << setfill(' ') << setw(10) << dec << n << internal << setw(12) << oct << n << internal << setw(9) << hex << uppercase << n << endl;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

However if I try to discard inputs that aren't numbers with this it won't read in the input after the letters:

```
if (cin.fail()) {
    cin.ignore();
}
```

How do I discard input but be able to read other input later on?

Sample Input:

```
23
678  786  abc
7777
```

Expected Output: dec, oct, hex

---

```
    23          27       17
   678        1246      2A6
   786        1422      312
  7777       17141     1E61
```

Comment: You are missing a call to `cin.clear()`. You need that to clear the `failbit`. As long as it's set, all operations immediately fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consume the offending content from `cin` and reset the error state. As long as `failbit` is set, all input operations will fail immediately.

```
while(1) {
if (cin >> n)
    cout << internal << setfill(' ') << setw(10) << dec << n << internal << setw(12) << oct << n << internal << setw(9) << hex << uppercase << n << endl;
else {
    if (cin.eof())
        break;
    cin.clear();               // Reset the error state
    std::string dummy;  
    if (!(cin >> dummy))       // Consume what ever non-integer you encountered
        break;
  } 
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can just always read a `std::string` and then try to parse that to a number with [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
for (std::string word; std::cin >> word;) {
    try {
        int n = std::stoi(word);
        // You output logic here
    }
    catch (std::exception&) {}
}
```

But this will probably overuse exceptions as you state that invalid input is not exceptional. On the upside, it means doing less logic "by hand".